# Sorting a string and removing characters

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
const int SIZE = 100;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *pStr, str[SIZE] = "", newStr[SIZE] = "", ch;
    int count = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

    cout << "Enter a number of mixed characters: ";
    cin.getline(str, SIZE);
    pStr = str;

    while (*pStr != '\0')
    {
        if (isalnum(*pStr))
            ch = toupper(*pStr);
        newStr[i++] = ch;

        if (*pStr = ' ')
            count++;
        pStr++;
    }
    newStr[i] = '\0';

    cout << strlen(str) - strlen(newStr) << " characters were filtered out, "
         << " out of which " << count << " whitespaces were encountered.\n";

    int temp;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(newStr) - 1; i++);
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < strlen(newStr); j++);
        {
            if (newStr[j] < newStr[i])  // sorts in alphabetical
            {                       // and numerical order 
                temp = newStr[i];           
                newStr[i] = newStr[j];
                newStr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "New sorted string: " << newStr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a code here which is supposed to take an input string and print it out in a certain order and remove other characters as well as spaces. Numbers and letters are supposed to be sorted in numerical and alphabetical order. So if you take for instance the input "khff &%/321", the output should be "123FFHK".

However, when I try the code with said input string, the output I get is "KHFFFFFF32". I was hoping for some tips on what parts of the code I need to take a closer look at to solve the problem.

Comment: I recommend you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: I also assume this is an exercise in pointers, arrays and C-style strings? Otherwise if you used standard classes and algorithms it would just be a couple of lines long.

Comment: `str[SIZE] = ""` does not do what you think it does. your sort algorithm is seriously bugged. take a look at `std::sort`, `std::remove_if` and `std::transform`

Comment: Each `for` loop you end it with semicolon (e.g. `for (i = 0; i < strlen(newStr) - 1; i++); `). Remove the semicolon after the for-loop first (maybe this could be one part of your problem?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also like to point out

```
if (isalnum(*pStr))
    ch = toupper(*pStr);
    newStr[i++] = ch;
```

the list line in this is not covered under the if condition,and for every special character read(&,%,/) you would be appending them to your newStr,hence you are getting additional Fs in your output.You must do something like:

```
if (isalnum(*pStr))
  {  ch = toupper(*pStr);
    newStr[i++] = ch;
   }
```

which will check whether your character is alnum or not and only append when if condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use this code to sort the string as you would like, then use the `erase` function to strip out non-alphanumeric characters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string word = "khff &%/123";
    word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), [](char ch){ return !::isalnum(ch); }), word.end());
    std::sort(word.begin(), word.end());
    std::cout << word << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the wide-character `iswalnum` when working with narrow characters? And a little optimization: Remove the unwanted characters first *then* sort.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take on how the program could be written to use the standard library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

#define USER_TYPES_INPUT // comment this line out to use own test stream
#ifdef USER_TYPES_INPUT
auto& my_cin = std::cin;
#else
std::stringstream my_cin{R"(khff&%/32 1)"};
#endif

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::cout << "Enter a number of mixed characters: \n";
    std::getline(my_cin, line);
    auto original_size = line.size();
    auto space_count = std::count_if(line.begin(), line.end(), [](auto c){return ::isblank(c); });
    line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), [](char c){ return !::isalnum(c); }), line.end());
    std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), [](auto& c){return ::toupper(c); });
    std::sort(line.begin(), line.end());
    std::cout << original_size - line.size() << " characters were filtered out, out of which "
        << space_count << " whitespace" << (space_count == 1 ? " was" : "s were") << " encountered.\n";
    std::cout << "New sorted string: " << line << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```